# Dropmenu with Foundation 5.2.2?

Tags: html, css, navigation, zurb-foundation, navbar

is using the Foundation can achieve this effect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyYqK.png ?

I would like to use 2 COLUMNS in the TopBar Menu: foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html

MegaMenu (codepen.io/winghouchan/pen/jnrDx/) from this thread: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/232-megamenu?page=2  it was not working properly on mobile view in Foundation 5.2.2.

Is there a way to display the two columns in the dropdown menu on latest Foundation 5.2.2?

Answer (score 0):

just add `column:2` via css3 because mobile devise support columns

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
  .dropdown-wrapper {
    background-color: #333333 !important;
   padding: 10px 0;
  column:2
   } 
   }
```